# Using exec() function to make a string the name of a class

Tags: python, string, class

I want to create some instances of a class and I want their names to be from a bunch of strings stored in a list, I use `exec` function to specify the names:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def get_fname(self):
        return(self.fname)


people = ["Paul","Steve","Martin","Jack"]
for item in people:
    exec("%s = %s" %(item,Person(item)))
```

but I get this Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-a79ddedb8e1d>", line 10, in <module>
exec("%s = %s" %(item,Person(item)))

File "<string>", line 1
    Paul = <__main__.Person object at 0x000001A31E1BA0D0>
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: _Why_ do you need (or choose to use) `exec()` for this? What specific constraints control which (if any) non-`exec()`-using answers are applicable or acceptable?

Comment: BTW, if your goal is to be able to serialize your `Person` to a string, and then deserialize it back to an object, (1) `repr()`, not `str()`, is appropriate to use that way; but (2) it'd be even better to use the pickle module, which is built specifically for the purpose.

Comment: I guess it should be `exec("%s = Person(%s)" %(item,repr(item)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Person` class needs a [`__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) to be nicely printable!

```py
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname  # or self.get_fname()
```

Further, there's no need to `exec()` these, and they can (*almost certainly should*) be put into some collection like a dictionary or a list instead

```py
my_dict = {}
for name in names:
    my_dict[name] = Person(name)
```

This will make the names the keys of the dictionary, so they can be referenced back later by-index `my_dict.get(some_name)`, which is probably what you want and much more maintainable than trying to keep every name as a new variable (probably wastes resources, what if someone had a name that was a builtin function you needed?..)

---

If you really did want to use `exec()` to create instances of your objects (though you needn't do this at all, nor actually twice as you were trying!), this is where you would want to define `__repr__(self)` - which should be written by you such that it can be used to create the parent object

A good example of this comes from Exceptions

```py
>>> ex = ValueError("something went wrong")
>>> print(ex)
something went wrong
>>> print(repr(ex))
ValueError('something went wrong')
```

Note how the **repr**esentation can be used to create a new instance of the original object

Comment: This is true, but it assumes that the OP's code _should_ work. I'm not sure that's the case -- it'd be better to do the assignment in a way that doesn't depend on `exec()` at all.

Comment: You're right; there's no need for them to `exec()`; let me make a more complete answer

Comment: ...and if their goal is to make a representation that can be run as Python code to get back the original object, that's the job for `repr()`, not `str()`. Perhaps an implementation vaguely like `def __repr__(self): return r'{self.__class__}(fname={self.name.repr()})'` or such?)